# Drupal 8 Composer Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages - commerceguys/intl

Tags: drupal, composer-php

[image]

[image]

I want to install it.
drupal.org/project/social
But also ssh I get an error.

I installed Composer and Drush.

```
composer-creator of the project goalgorill / social_templat to: giant-master Dr --no-interaction
```

I get an error in the command enters the picture.

Comment: In the future please avoid using images to show textual information. They are hard to view, aren't searchable, don't provide users with copyable text, and aren't accessible. Instead, copy and pasted the text directly into your question. Depending on the content, you might also need to use the "format as code" and "format as quote" features in the question editor.

Comment: Ok, understand. Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Composer is telling you exactly what is wrong:

> the requested PHP extension bcmath is missing from your system

and how to fix it:

> To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in those ini files

Install and enable [the bcmath extension](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php). The exact process will depend on your operating system and how you installed PHP.

Comment: [bcmath]
; Number of decimal digits for all bcmath functions.
; http://php.net/bcmath.scale
bcmath.scale = 0

Comment: Sorry.
Php.ini file already exists. The problem is still not solved.
Could you write more clearly?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15609273/yum-install-php-bcmath-requires-php-commonx86-64-5-3-3-22-el6

Comment: Still problem, please help me

Comment: @Enes, people on Stack Overflow are usually helping in their free time without any compensation. You might not get a response immediately. Please be patient.

Comment: @Enes, I'm sure that you do have a `php.ini` file. Composer is telling you to install and enable [PHP's arbitrary precision math extension](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php). You linked to another question about installing bcmath, but I'm not clear what you mean by that. Are you using CentOS, like that other user is? Did you try running `yum install php-bcmath`? Did you get an error? What did it say?

Comment: [root@vps216570 yum.repos.d]# yum install php-bcmath
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-bcmath.x86_64 0:5.4.16-36.3.el7_2 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-36.3.el7_2 for package: php-bcmath-5.4.16-36.3.el7_2.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Comment: Error: Package: php-bcmath-5.4.16-36.3.el7_2.x86_64 (updates)
           Requires: php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-36.3.el7_2
           Installed: php-common-5.6.24-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php56)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.6.24-1.el7.remi
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-36.el7_1.x86_64 (base)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-36.el7_1

Comment: Available: php-common-5.4.16-36.1.el7_2.1.x86_64 (updates)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-36.1.el7_2.1
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-36.3.el7_2.x86_64 (updates)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-36.3.el7_2
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest

Comment: @Enes, you already found another question discussing this. (You [linked to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39016346/drupal-8-composer-your-requirements-could-not-be-resolved-to-an-installable-set/39016600?noredirect=1#comment65386034_39016600) above). Did you try any of the answers you found there? [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19195761/354577) looks useful to me: `yum install php-bcmath --enablerepo=remi`.

Comment: ]# yum install php-bcmath --enablerepo=remi
Loaded plugins: replace
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-bcmath.x86_64 0:5.4.45-11.el7.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.45-11.el7.remi for package: php-bcmath-5.4.45-11.el7.remi.x86_64

Comment: I think the problem elsewhere.
I'll tell you what I did.
I threw Server format.

Comment: CentOS installation was 7.
I did Sentora installation.
Then I upgraded from 5.6.20 PHP version 5.4. I looked php upgrade http://forums.sentora.org/showthread.php?tid=780 here.

Comment: @Enes, following your link it looks like you might need to enable two repos: `yum install php-bcmath --enablerepo=remi,remi-php56`.

Comment: Thank you very much to everyone who helped.
I solved the problem.

I stopped using CentOS.
I installed Ubuntu. I installed Plesk. Then I re-established composer. It was a clean install.

Apparently there was a server problem.